# How can I design a background with a red wave like this in Figma?

Tags: android, figma, screenshot

[image]

I have created a similar screen but I also want to design a background with a red wave like this... Where should I start?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: Pretty basic knowledge there to set that up in Figma. What have you tried ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are struggling with in the background? Is it the red shape? The transparent effect that suggests a phone? Something else?

Comment: @curious yes that red shape .it is like a wave when all screenshot combined

Comment: @SaurabhDhage I edited the question to add the part about the red shape. It's however less likely that you will get answers since you accepted an answer before this was clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are a beginner who is now at point zero and cannot show any own attempts. Many of us like to close their questions, but here's my answer:

Anyone who has practiced (=worked tutorials, studied functions, constructed their own stuff) few weeks with a vector drawing program, for ex. Illustrator, Inkscape or Affinity Designer builds this with no problems. Even Photoshop, GIMP or other capable raster image editors with some text and vector tools can be used. You simply layer the needed elements. Some of them can be downloaded, some of them must be created by yourself. Screenshots are rarely usable material because they do not have enough resolution. They lose their sharpness if they are not shown exactly in their original pixel dimensions and original physical size.

There's a couple of hitches:

1. If you want to make your own creation, not a copy, you must be able to imagine it. Draw sketches on paper until you know what you want.
2. The copyright. In your home you can make with no problems nearly any images you want, but as soon as you show or give them to others, upload them to web, try to sell them or in some other way publish or distribute them, you must respect copyright. That limits how you can use elements which belong to some known phone or a known product or they only are already created by someone else.

For example phone manufacturers have published very restricting rules how their phones or items of the screens of their phone operating system can be legally used in graphic works. The same is valid for all business logos.

Before making anything learn concepts copyright and licensing. Big companies have an army of lawyers to force copyright violators to pay.

**ADD:** I am not Figma user. I have red that Figma is user interface design tool. Your image is not user interface, but a drawing from an advertisement. It has texts, logo shapes, some common phone screen elements, a partially transparent white screen frame, a blurry dark element as a shadow and the curved background shapes.

As I said, this has nothing which is impossible or difficult in general drawing programs. Check for ex. this SVG in Inkscape: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1du9iejydpgmb86/onead000..svg?dl=0 . The Objects panel and Fill&Stroke panel should show how it's put together.

[image]

Its texts and shapes are moved apart in the next screenshot (Inkscape):

[image]

In this site you generally will get nothing by saying "I cannot create the background" An answer like this is an exception. It collects easily a bunch of downvotes and blaming comments from users who like to see something a little more demanding or at least a well constructed question. You should say what detail in the background construction is the problem and show some own attempt, too.

Comment: Note the question is closed for a lack of focus, not because OP hasn't shown any attempts.

Comment: There's focus: how to do this or something resembling. It's quite small area in whole human life. I suggested as a solution to learn to draw. Lack of focus is, of course, fully legal reason to cose.

Comment: @user287001 Thank You for your response it helped me :)